# rolling average to multiple variables in R using data.table package

Tags: r, data.table, moving-average

I would like to get rolling average for each of the numeric variables that I have. Using data.table package, I know how to compute for a single variable. But how should I revise the code so it can process multiple variables at a time rather than revising the variable name and repeat this procedure for several times? Thanks.

Suppose I have other numeric variables named as "V2", "V3", and "V4".

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data)
setkey(data,Receptor,date)
data[ , `:=` ('RollConc' = rollmean(AvgConc, 48, align="left", na.pad=TRUE)) , by=Receptor]
```

A copy of my sample data can be found at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86_a8ltyoL3OE9KTUstYmRRbFk/view?usp=sharing

I would like to get 5-hour rolling means for "AvgConc","TotDep","DryDep", and "WetDep" by each receptor.

Comment: Please show some example `data`

Comment: A sample data has uploaded. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I have restrictions to download data.  Somebody will try it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked very well.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a numeric variable "Event" to mark each rolling mean calculation for each receptor? For example, for Receptor 1, the first rolling mean will be marked as Event[1], and the last rolling mean calculated will be Event[n]? And for Receptor 2, the rolling means will also be marked as Event j in 1 to length[rollingmean]

Comment: hi, Vicki, would you mind sharing the test dt? would like toi study more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From your description you want something like this, which is similar to one example that can be found in [one of the **data.table** vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = rlnorm(10), z = runif(10), g = c("a", "b"), key = "g")
library(zoo)
DT[, paste0("ravg_", c("x", "y")) := lapply(.SD, rollmean, k = 3, na.pad = TRUE), 
   by = g, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
```

Comment: A further question... I see the code computed my data but results are not saved as variables... How can I save those rolling averages into a new dataframe as variables?

Comment: I don't understand. They are saved as columns of the data.table. Why do you want them in a different data.table? If you must, you can always subset the data.table.

Comment: can be improved in future once [data.table#626](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/626) will be implemented

Comment: Is there anyway to add a numeric variable "Event" to mark each rolling mean calculation for each receptor? For example, for Receptor 1, the first rolling mean will be marked as Event[1], and the last rolling mean calculated will be Event[n]? And for Receptor 2, similarly, the rolling means will also be marked as Event j in 1 to length[rollingmean]

Answer (score 13):

Now, one can use the `frollmean` function in the `data.table` package for this.

```
library(data.table)    
xy <- c("x", "y")
DT[, (xy):= lapply(.SD, frollmean, n = 3, fill = NA, align="center"), 
                                   by = g, .SDcols =  xy]
```

Here, I am replacing the x and y columns by the rolling average.

---

```
# Data
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = rlnorm(10), z = runif(10), 
                                g = c("a", "b"), key = "g")
```

Comment: this answer is suboptimial, there is not need for lapply, just use frollmean(.SD, ...) directly. it is vectorized and will be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Cliff did not correct his answer despite my comment was made long time ago, therefore submitting proper usage of vectorized arguments in `frollmean`

```r
DT[, paste0("r_", vars) := frollmean(.SD, n=w, align=align), by = g, .SDcols = vars]
```

and a benchmark

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
n = 1e6
DT = data.table(V1 = rnorm(n), V2 = rlnorm(n), V3 = runif(n), g = rep(c("a","b"),n/2), key="g")
vars = c("V1","V2","V3")
library(zoo)
w = 48
align = "left"

roland = function(DT) DT[, paste0("r_", vars) := lapply(.SD, rollmean, k=w, na.pad=TRUE, align=align), by = g, .SDcols = vars]
cliff = function(DT) DT[, paste0("r_", vars) := lapply(.SD, frollmean, n=w, fill=NA, align=align), by = g, .SDcols = vars]                                   
jan = function(DT) DT[, paste0("r_", vars) := frollmean(.SD, n=w, align=align), by = g, .SDcols = vars]

DT1 = copy(DT)
DT2 = copy(DT)
DT3 = copy(DT)
system.time(a1 <- roland(DT1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.776   0.079   0.774
system.time(a2 <- cliff(DT2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.102   0.000   0.029 
system.time(a3 <- jan(DT3))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.064   0.000   0.023

all.equal(DT1, DT2)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(DT1, DT3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Most importantly, the more variables, the faster `jan` than `cliff` will be as they are computed in parallel.

---

This can be easily observed if we scale up dataset and remove `[.data.table` overhead from the benchmark:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
n = 1e7
nth = 8
DT = as.data.table(replicate(nth, rnorm(n)))
setDTthreads(nth)
w = 48
align = "left"
DT2 = copy(DT)
DT3 = copy(DT)

system.time(a2 <- lapply(DT2, frollmean, n=w, align=align))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.316   0.244   0.561 
system.time(a3 <- frollmean(DT2, w, align=align))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.064   0.357   0.183
```